# Setting factor levels and subsetting for multiple boxplot series in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, subset, boxplot

A portion of a data file is shown below for which I can create plots using ggplot2. 
The file is read in with headers=TRUE and stringsAsFactors=FALSE. Then:

```
    respiration$Time<-as.numeric(respiration$Time))

    ggplot(data=respiration,aes(x=Time,y=as.numeric(as.character(respiration$X0.41_522.2))))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Time)))+scale_fill_manual(values=c("2"='white',"12"='white',"24"='white',"36"='white'))+
    geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.01))+
    ggtitle("some compound")+
    ylab("Intensity")+xlab("Hours")+theme(legend.position="none")+
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,4E7))+
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,40))+
    stat_summary(aes(group=factor(Time)),fun.data="mean_cl_boot",colour="red")+
    stat_smooth(aes(group=factor(1)),se=FALSE,method="loess")+
    theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank())





  Genotype  Time    ID  Temperature Treatment   0.41_522.2  0.41_258.11     0.42_527.16     0.42_360.15     0.43_365.1 
Salinas     2       7       25      Agar        7687155.049 11175204.68     13230240.69     22774983.56     34439569.05
Salinas     2       8       25      Agar        1713206.815 1746016.676     4502488.407     9063059.137     24629121.47
Salinas     2       9       25      Agar        914071.6085 1124905.211     1904392.406     5194590.864     12827777.79
Salinas     2       10      25      Agar        1347683.743 1499201.037     3585477.632     6917994.766     19634655.68
Salinas     2       11      25      Agar        1605104.23  1538321.506     4204065.255     8621464.214     23870186.29
Salinas     2       12      25      Agar        700952.9606 979183.9824     1807856.593     5420989.584     11947592.7
Salinas     12      7       25      Agar        3146028.898 1969085.431     7448511.299     16657110.41     44682871.81
Salinas     12      8       25      Agar        5386677.411 3846305.708     12236342.92     25169138.26     59950390.63
Salinas     12      9       25      Agar        1286114.635 722906.1406     2794505.637     9481895.382     30506314.05
Salinas     12      10      25      Agar        5354226.033 3386725.041     11784456.5      29645430.51     59248887.66
Salinas     12      11      25      Agar        748492.385  740351.3929     1523802.155     8359841.052     16359084.05
Salinas     12      12      25      Agar        858499.9758 575103.9487     1905007.092     8912330.085     18842273.56
Salinas     24      7       25      Agar        667094.93   303363.0331     1163334.585     3157785.164     12044157.87
Salinas     24      9       25      Agar        530456.9694 301920.1723     506135.6222     2265239.959     5893314.03
Salinas     24      10      25      Agar        858462.6456 456174.4145     555120.596      3299599.66      5523333.797
Salinas     24      11      25      Agar        692168.542  298962.6992     750788.6791     2603185.012     7824435.531
Salinas     24      12      25      Agar        4889407.02  863217.2961     4043759.224     13581223.81     20775934.23
Salinas     36      7       25      Agar        694220.2582 1032292.333     1122184.33      1934143.562     4981677.673
Salinas     36      8       25      Agar        298106.1061 264547.3778     269777.3095     800179.5481     1752898.77
Salinas     36      9       25      Agar        129491.3269 262669.2395     921.6464545     534094.1204     968189.6005
Salinas     36      10      25      Agar        244119.2273 268969.6876     267995.1597     703121.8463     2017272.657
Salinas     36      11      25      Agar        80468.06667 2873.859524     2873.859524     2873.859524     2873.859524
Salinas     36      12      25      Agar        232242.6907 905.4295936     905.4295936     511567.7204     1541946.598
```

This is the basic format of the plots that I would like. However, I would 
like to use all the treatments in my study, shown in the subset of data 
below. There are 5 identity columns before the data starts for each sample.
Three of these identity columns: Genotype, Temperature, and Treatment, have
two levels: Salinas or RNAi, 25 or 35, and Agar or ABA, respectively. What I 
would like to do is keep the x-axis and y-axis the same, but plot each of 
the treatments, there are 8 total using each combination, on the same 
graph. For example: Salinas at 25 on Agar over the time course of the Time
column. The next treatment Salinas at 35 on Agar, etc. The ID column is just
for counting the replicates in each class.

```
Genotype    Time    ID  Temperature Treatment   0.41_522.2  0.41_258.11     0.42_527.16     0.42_360.15     0.43_365.1  0.43_202.17 
    RNAi        2       7       25      ABA         5039        7422            8679            49576           90494       618738
    RNAi        2       7       25      Agar        1516        3683            2343            25396           32525       892735
    RNAi        12      7       25      ABA         170         1656            579             11413           24518       277258
    RNAi        12      7       25      Agar        2531        3632            3292            37569           86284       2303883
    RNAi        24      7       25      ABA         1094        6791            5               40115           79347       1220589
    RNAi        24      7       25      Agar        1247        1518            2146            12985           28139       2650504
    RNAi        36      7       25      ABA         2276        16383           4987            94464           231996      1336160
    RNAi        36      7       25      Agar        331         8               8               3925            11779       4554882
    RNAi        2       7       35      ABA         1598        7257            5005            23631           76097       2441766
    RNAi        2       7       35      Agar        2274        9542            8307            43152           133585      2541899
    RNAi        12      7       35      ABA         1039        7630            4486            13465           93716       2146027
    RNAi        12      7       35      Agar        2946        6497            5338            20105           64423       299289
    RNAi        24      7       35      Agar        151         2998            132             1720            8079        1283399
    RNAi        36      7       35      ABA         4           9409            1109            4342            22157       10843
    RNAi        36      7       35      Agar        2           5967            255             3150            10983       1425159
    Salinas     2       7       25      ABA         2128        2650            6294            19401           55034       2258538
    Salinas     2       7       25      Agar        27630       40168           47554           81862           123789      217905  
    Salinas     2       7       35      ABA         305         2759            1136            4056            13781       778439
    Salinas     2       7       35      Agar        395         2181            1497            4580            19018       765146
    Salinas     12      7       25      ABA         488         3               1585            13856           29628       2376100
    Salinas     12      7       25      Agar        11308       7078            26773           59872           160607      77740
    Salinas     12      7       35      ABA         674         5755            2193            8081            30457       1611051
    Salinas     12      7       35      Agar        397         3477            1419            6182            19834       1090362
    Salinas     24      7       25      ABA         1409        3608            1815            31308           68367       1149736
    Salinas     24      7       25      Agar        2398        1090            4181            11350           43291       646527
    Salinas     24      7       35      ABA         383         4609            1616            3911            17137       1167969
    Salinas     24      7       35      Agar        12965       52846           41744           27943           60272       427210
    Salinas     36      7       25      ABA         152         3               324             8745            16137       1271203
    Salinas     36      7       25      Agar        2495        3710            4034            6952            17906       841374
    Salinas     36      7       35      ABA         30222       57212           90224           41898           96592       497250
    Salinas     36      7       35      Agar        243         5029            1073            3811            9889        1119949
```

I am not entirely sure which functions, or combinations of functions I 
should employ to make this happen with my data and graphs. I first attempted
reshape() and melted the data, but this lost all the individual sample
class information.
I know that I have to subset the data, somehow by each factor 
level, but have been unable to find examples with as many factors as I have.

Thank you so much for any help or direction.

Ok. Thank you for the feedback thus far. I have played with the code you suggested so far and have not arrived at the desired solution.

I will try and make what I am trying to do more clear. 
In the first data set I posted here, there is data for only 1 treatment--Genotype: Salinas, Temperature: 25, and Treatment: Agar. This is plotted as a single boxplot series for an individual compound(column), one at a time over a continuous x-axis, Time. This treatment can be abbreviated as S25Ag (Salinas at 25 degrees on Agar).

The second block of data posted has 8 combinations of treatments, using the same method of abbreviating as above:

```
S25Ag (Salinas at 25 degrees on Agar)
S35Ag
S25ABA
S35ABA
R25Ag (RNAi at 25 degrees on Agar)
R35Ag
R25ABA
R35ABA
```

Each of these treatment combinations has a full time course from 2-36 hours (4 time points) for each compound (column) measurement.

What I am trying to do is make a single graph, for an individual compound (column), over a continuous Time x-axis, that has all eight treatments plotted simultaneously as boxplots.

Is it more clear what I am trying to do with this explanation?

Comment: You should not have to use 
y=as.numeric(as.character(respiration$X0.41_522.2)) 
y=X0.41_522.2
should work.
Try using reshape2::melt(respiration, id = 1:4) to reshape your data

Comment: Thank you so much! After struggling with my parenthesis for a bit, I got it working without the y=as.numeric(as.character(respiration$X0.41_522.2)), and just the y=X0.41_522.2. On the reshape2() melting. I tried it two different ways: melt(respiration,id=1:4), and melt(respiration,id=1:5). The id=1:5 gives me a new structure, where Genotype and Treatment are characters, Time, ID, and Temperature are integers, and then I have a variable column that is now factors with as many levels as columns in my data, followed by a value row for all the corresponding values.

Comment: Using id=1:4 gives me a variable row as factors for all the columns of my data, and a value row as factors with 2 levels, for "ABA" and "Agar". Don't I need to set Genotype, and Temperature as factors with two levels as well? Or do I just do this manually: df$column<-as.factor(df$column)? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, cannot count, should be 1:5

Comment: Ok, so if I melt as such: melt(respiration,id=1:5), and then put it in ggplot2:

Comment: ggplot(meltrespiration,aes(x=Time,y=variable,group=value)), without passing anything else to aes,  I get a graph that doesn't make any sense. If I do it like this: ggplot(meltrespiration,aes(x=Time,y=variable,group=value))+
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Time)))+
geom_boxplot(aes(y=Genotype,col="Genotype"))+
geom_boxplot(aes(y=Temperature,col="Temperature"))+
geom_boxplot(aes(y=Treatment,col="Treatment")) my console just thinks forever and never executes the graph. I think it is trying to plot all columns on one graph...?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want but ggplot(meltrespiration, aes(x = variable, y = value) + geom_boxplot() would get a simple boxplot. You could show more with  ggplot(meltrespiration, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Genotype) + geom_boxplot(). You could get still more by adding a facet(), or by using interaction(). See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/boxplot-with-respect-to-two-factors-using-ggplot2-in-r